# Regex to replace a repeating string pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, replaceall

I need to replace a repeated pattern within a word with each basic construct unit. For example
I have the string "TATATATA" and I want to replace it with "TA". Also I would probably replace more than 2 repetitions to avoid replacing normal words.

I am trying to do it in Java with replaceAll method.

Comment: Where is your code / regex ?

Comment: If you are already using replaceAll(), what is the problem? replaceAll does exactly what you want to to do (if you have a simple pattern as the one described above).

Comment: I don't want to replace only "TATATATA" but any string that is repeating like that. @TheLostMind I don't have any regex ideas.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Do you mean any repeating characters like TATATATA or YTYTYT or ABCABCABC which may be present in a string ?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to match any repeating patterns. What is that thing with my code? I don't have any code this is why I am asking.

Comment: Look Ahead, Look back with Regex, String#contains(), String#indexOf() etc can be used for this.. But show us your effort

Comment: Guys, we are talking about an one-liner probably. Either you know it or you don't. I don't see how that "show the code" is helping people. Thanks.

Comment: @ddmichael: I do not think it is possible to write code that finds *any repeating pattern*. Technically all text is then a repeating pattern, only that it might just be repeated once.

Comment: @Pphoenix: I was afraid of that. I am looking for patterns within a word though, do you think that's possible?

Comment: @ddmichael: Yes! You only have define what you see as a pattern. Example: If you have TAT, is that a pattern where every other letter is a T? Or are you looking for at least TATA? If you find a repeating pattern you would like to find, it will be possible to define code for it.

Comment: @Pphoenix: No I am not interested in TAT, where every other letter is a T. Ideally I would like to replace A{3,} with A, TA{3,} with TAT{3,} and so on. Hence repeating patterns of one or more continuous characters.

Comment: see my answer, i think i got it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want this (works for any length of the repeated string):

```
String result = source.replaceAll("(.+)\\1+", "$1")
```

Or alternatively, to prioritize shorter matches:

```
String result = source.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1")
```

It matches first a group of letters, and then it again (using back-reference within the match pattern itself). I tried it and it seems to do the trick.

---

Example

```
String source = "HEY HEY duuuuuuude what'''s up? Trololololo yeye .0.0.0";

System.out.println(source.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1"));

// HEY dude what's up? Trolo ye .0
```

Answer (score 1):

You had better use a `Pattern` here than `.replaceAll()`. For instance:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN 
    = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z]{2,}?)\\1+\\b");

//...

final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
ret = m.replaceAll("$1");
```

---

edit: example:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    System.out.println("TATATA GHRGHRGHRGHR"
        .replaceAll("\\b([A-Za-z]{2,}?)\\1+\\b", "$1"));
}
```

This prints:

```
TA GHR
```

Comment: Didn't work, prints the whole string. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yep indeed, I was trying with an extra character at the end, like "TATATAT".

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a regex solution:

```
(\\w)(\\w)(\\1\\2){2,};
```

`(\w)(\w)`: matches every pair of consecutive word characters (`(.)(.)` will catch every consecutive pair of characters of any type), storing them in [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) 1 and 2. `(\\1\\2)` matches anytime the characters in those groups are repeated again immediately afterward, and `{2,}` matches when it repeats two or more times (`{2,10}` would match when it repeats more than one but less than ten times).

```
String s = "hello TATATATA world";    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(\\w)(\\1\\2){2,}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
    //prints "TATATATA"
```

Comment: I am afraid that prints only the first letter. Thanks for your answer!